# Require.js r.js: Compile directory to single file

Tags: requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

Is there any way to configure RequireJS to compile an entire directory to a single file? I don't mean the normal use case of the 'out' setting. I'll try to explain by example. If I have the following project structure:

```
- app
  - main.js
  - menu.js
- module
  - file-a.js
  - file-b.js
```

Then let's say I want to compile the 'app' directory to a single file. I don't care about it's dependencies - even if it requires 'module' or either of its files, they won't be included. Even if main.js doesn't require menu.js, it'll be included anyway. The resultant output file would define 'app/main' and 'app/menu' modules.

Likewise, if I wanted to compile the 'module' directory, the file would define 'module/file-a' and 'module/file-b' regardless of what other dependencies were defined.

I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `dir` parameter in build file of require instead of just `name` parameter.

You can read more about building whole directory on requirejs documentation - [Optimize Whole Project](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#wholeproject)

If you write build file something like `app-build.js`-

```
({
   appDir: ".",
   baseUrl: "app",
   dir: "../app-build",
})
```

and if you run `r.js -o app.build.js` then it will create

- app-build

  - main.js
  - menu.js

Here `menu.js` will not be include in `main.js` unless it is required somewhere in `main.js` source.

Comment: It doesn't have the single file output though, which is what I'm after. I've already got Traceur creating the AMD code. Now I just want to create my bundles for each part of the project.